# Response Customized Object Transaction in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, transactions

I've created a transaction but I'd like to return all data which has been created in one json. I'd like to do this using Resources in Laravel 5.5.

This is my transaction:

```
$firstUser = DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {

        //Create Group Campany
        $groupCompany = \App\GroupCompany::create([
            'name' => $request['nameGroupCompany'],
            'cod' => $request['codGroupCompany'],
        ]);

        //Create Company
        $company = \App\Company::create([
            'group_company_id' => $groupCompany->id,
            'name' => $request['nameCompany'],
            'cod' => $request['codCompany'],
        ]);

        //Create Group User
        $groupUser = \App\GroupUser::create([
            'name' => 'Admin',
            'admin' => 1,
        ]);
        $groupUser->companies()->attach($company->id);            

        //Create Person
        $person = \App\Person::create([
            'firstName' => $request['name'],
            'middleName' => $request['middleName'],
            'lastName' => $request['lastName'],
            'dateOfBirth' => $request['dateOfBirth'],
        ]);
        $person->groupUsers()->attach($groupUser->id);

        //Create User
        $newUser = \App\User::create([
            'person_id' => $person->id,
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),
        ]);

        return ??????;

    });
```

And finally I call my Resource:

```
return new FirstUserResource($firstUser);
```

What should I do?

Thank you very much.

Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save info in a `array` before save them like below:

```
$groupCompanya = array('name' => $request['nameGroupCompany'],
                               'cod' => $request['codGroupCompany']);

$groupCompany = \App\GroupCompany::create($groupCompanya);
```

Gather all data into a new `array`:

```
$result  = array("groupCompany"=> $groupCompanya, "company" => $companya, "groupUser" => $groupUsera, "person"=>$persona, "newUser"=>$newUsera);
```

after convert it to `json` and `return` it:

```
$json = array("result" => $result);
return json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning all the data as a single json I think Collections will help you here?

```
$collection = collect([var1,var2]);
return $collection->toJson();
```